# Volume Keys + Google maps V2

Tags: android, button, google-maps-android-api-2

Does anyone knows how to make a google maps V2 on android to zoom in/out by clicking on the Volume keys?

I use this code but it does not work :

```
     @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (mUseVolumeKeys)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        if (mMap != null)
                        {
                            mMap.zoomIn();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        if (mMap != null)
                        {
                            mMap.zoomOut();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

I have an error on the Mmap.zoomIn / out that says 
     The method zoomIn() is undefined for the type GoogleMap

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no `zoomIn()` method on Maps V2.

If you want to zoom, get the current camera position via `getCameraPosition()`, update its `zoom`, and then use `moveCamera()` or `animateCamera()` to change to your revised `CameraPosition`.

Comment: @MobiusApps: Both zooming in and zooming out involve modifying the zoom level of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats the solution for you:

```
void ZoomOut()
{
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut();
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

the same for ZoomIn()